# jpql: group by month from milliseconds

Tags: jpql

I want to get the count of new users per month. A month should be indicated by the UTC timestamp (in ms as `Long`) of the first day of the month at 0:00h.

This approach may explain what I want to do:

Entity

```
class User {
    @NotNull
    private Long createdAt; // utc timestamp in ms
}
```

Repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT new UserRepository$NewUser(to_start_of_month_in_ms(user.createdAt), count(user.id)) "
        + "FROM User user "
        + "GROUP BY to_start_of_month_in_ms(user.createdAt) ")
    List<NewUser> findNewUsersPerMonth();

    @Getter
    @AllArgsConstructor
    public static class NewUser {
        private Long startOfMonth; // utc timestamp in ms
        private Integer count;
    }
}
```

What can I use for `to_start_of_month_in_ms`, i.e. how can we derive the start of the month from the `createdAt` field in the group by clause. What should the 
`@Query` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is not possible in JPQL because it does not support date truncation etc. Using a native query for PSQL I came up with this:

```
public interface CountPerMonth {
    Integer getCount(); // count within the month
    Long getStartOfMonth(); // timestamp in ms
}

@Query(nativeQuery = true, value = ""
    + "SELECT COUNT(u.id) AS count, "
    + "  DATE_PART('EPOCH', DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',TO_TIMESTAMP(u.created_at/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'))*1000 AS startOfMonth "
    + "FROM user u "
    + "GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('MONTH',TO_TIMESTAMP(u.created_at/1000) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') "
    + "ORDER BY startOfMonth ")
List<CountPerMonth> findNewUsersPerMonth();
```